# Why this lock statement does not work

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

So I have this fairly simple code. Take a look.

```
var monitor = new object();

var result = 0;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var childTaskFactory = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        childTaskFactory
            .StartNew<int>(() => CreateRequest()) // this methods just return the integer value 10
            .ContinueWith(task => { lock (monitor) { result += task.Result; } });
    }
}).Wait();
```

Basically I am instantiating a new object to be used for acquiring lock. then I am creating an `int` variable which is set to 0. After that I am creating one parent `Task` which will contain 5 child `Task`s and all of those child task call a method called `CreateRequest` which just return a number 10 (don't mind the name of the method). Each child `Task` has a continuation which acquires lock on the `monitor` and just adds number 10 returned by the `CreateRequest` method to the `result` variable. At the end of the program I expect the variable `result` to contain the value 50. But it does not. I mean sometimes it does but some times it is set to 20, 30 or 40. Apparently either I am misunderstanding how to use `lock` statement or there is something wrong with the implementation. Most probably I have some mistake in a code. This code is inside the `static Main` method of the `Program` class.

Comment: In addition to the points made by the answers so far, I note also that this code is needlessly complicated. If your intention is to start five tasks and then synchronously wait for all to be finished then make an array of five tasks, fill in the array with the five started tasks, and then call `Task.WaitAll`, passing the array.

Comment: this was just an example code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your main task completes when all of the other tasks have started. It doesn't wait for them all to *finish*. So sometimes you're capturing the value of `result` before all of the child tasks have run.

As a test, put a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` after the `Wait()`, and you'll see that `result` is updated as expected. But don't use that for production code. Rather, write code that waits for all of the child tasks to finish.

Comment: a book stated that if I would wait for the parent task, child tasks would be waited as well. apparently it does not. the book also suggested to use Task.Run for child attach but as I know Task.Run denies child attach,

Comment: @Dima If you where using `async/await` the book would be correct. Do you even know what `AttachedToParent` does, and are you sure you need it?

Comment: No. The book did not state anything about async/await

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the code correctly, it's not actually waiting for all 5 tasks to complete.  Instead, it's waiting for all 5 tasks to be started, during which time apparently one or more of the tasks may complete, giving you 10, 20, 30, or 40 rather than 50.

[Here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of waiting on more than one task to complete.  You'll want the `WaitAll` version, not the `WaitAny`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also examine what is happening by adding the child tasks into a List and then adding a breakpoint at the end. If you then examine the objects in the Locals window you will see that the status of some tasks will still be Running.

Note that adding the tasks into a List may affect the execution and cause the result to equal 50 more often.